# Convert negative polygons to positive coordinates - Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, polygon, snap.svg

I want to keep my points(x, y) always positive.

I have an array with these values:

```
(points) [-916, 214, 10, 214, 10, 362, 200, 362, 200, 764, -916, 764]
            X    Y    X   Y    X   Y    X    Y    X    Y     X    Y
```

Is there a algorithm that can shift these points to their origin so that the coordinates stay always positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get first the minimum values of `x` and `y` and then map a new array with the correction.

> Minimum values
>
> ```
> [-916, 0]
> ```
>
> Conversion
>
> ```
> [-916,  214,   10,  214,   10,  362,  200,  362,  200,  764, -916,  764] original
> [   0,  214,  926,  214,  926,  362, 1116,  362, 1116,  764,    0,  764] updated
> ```

```js
var data = [-916, 214, 10, 214, 10, 362, 200, 362, 200, 764, -916, 764];
    min = [0, 0];
    
data.forEach(function (v, i) {
    if (v < min[i % 2]) {
        min[i % 2] = v;
    }
});

console.log(min);
console.log(data.map(function (v, i) {
    return v - min[i % 2];
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Is it possible to reverse the response with absolute coordinates again in to relative?

Comment: yes, by storing the minimum values. then you need to add the values in the loop.